# Facing crash to check special character in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a `NSString` stored in `cell.lblTitle.text`. I am converting this `NSString` to `NSMutableAttributedString` with following code.

```
text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[cell.lblTitle.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                               options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                    documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

[text setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:labelFont} range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
             value:[UIColor darkGrayColor]
             range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
```

When I print `cell.lblTitle.text` and its length in console then the following is my output:

```
po cell.lblTitle.text

Address: HM<MM-
UU@FF-
Mobile,
Alabama,
123456-
United States

po [cell.lblTitle.text length]
61
```

And when I print **text** which is my `NSMutableAttributedString`. The output in console is:

```
po text
Address: HM{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.333333 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7aebc0f0> font-family: \"Futura-Medium\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}

po [text length]
11
```

Following is my crash log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of
> bounds'

So, the string after special character "<" is not identified and my app crashes. How can I manage this special character "<" so I get the output `[text length] = 61`.

Comment: is this (<UICTFont:) have  close tag ( > ) ... ? or not

Comment: no that is not actually tag. it is treated as  a special character in this case.

Comment: add the crash log please ?

Comment: please refer updated answer for crash log

Comment: [text length] - 1 put and check and which line did you face crash ?

Comment: Actually as a output I want entire text of cell.lblTitle.text whose lenght is 61 but when I convert it to NSMutableAttributedString its length is 11. So, when I convert it to NSMutableAttributedString I am not able to get length 61. That is my main issue. If I got length of NSMutableAttributedString as 61 then perhaps my problem will be resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79734/discussion-between-spynet-and-iphone).

Comment: Why using `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`? Is there really HTML in your text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text isn't html so don't try to create it as such. Just use `initWithString:` to create the attributed string directly from the text.